# What does a variable superscript above a set mean?

Tags: sequences-and-series, general-topology

I'm not entirely sure I've worded this correctly. An example of what I mean is...

$$U = \{0,1\}^n$$

What is the meaning of the superscript?

Comment: Repeated cross products. In your case, $U$ is the set of $n$-tuples, each entry of which is 0 or 1.

Comment: @CarlHeckman, I found https://www.mathsisfun.com/algebra/vectors-cross-product.html because I didn't know what you meant by "cross products". I'm afraid I don't understand how this set has anything to do with vectors. However, I believe you are saying $U$ ends up being a set of $n$ number of 3-vector sets?

Comment: I think Carl meant, repeated *Cartesian* products.

Comment: If $n = 2$, then $U = \{\{0, 0\}, \{0, 1\}, \{1, 0\}, \{1, 1\}\}$?

Comment: @Allenph Note quite: $U^2 = \{ (0,0), (0,1), (1,0), (1,1) \}$ (the round parentheses denote ordered pairs while brackets denote unordered sets. So while $\{1,0\} = \{0,1\}$ we have $(1,0) \neq (0,1)$.)

Comment: @Stefan Ahhh. Did you mean to say $U^2 = /{(0, 0), (0, 1), (1, 0), (1, 1)/}$? Shouldn't it be $U = /{(0, 0), (0, 1), (1, 0), (1, 1)/}$?

Comment: Yes, you are right ;-)

Comment: Ah, I left out "Cartesian" ... I meant "Cartesian cross product". (Thanks, Gerry)